# Do I need to escape characters in SQL Deploy database password? How?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have an Azure release pipeline task to run SQL scripts from a file against an on-prem database. In the DevOps UI, I specify the server name, database name, SQL user name, and password. The task is failing with the message "Login failed for user 'mydbuser'".

I have confirmed that the username and password are correct. I have successfully connected to the database with SQL Server Management Studio using the same credentials.

The password begins with an @ character. Does that character need to be escaped? If so, how do I accomplish that in the deployment task UI?

I have tried using ` before it, or surrounding the password with single or double quotes. Nothing has worked so far.

**UPDATE:**
I have verified that running the command in Powershell with the @ escaped with ` works successfully.

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -Username mydbuser -ServerInstance 192.168.3.42\DB -Database MyDatabase -Query "SELECT * FROM Schools" -Password @pswrd
```

Results in >>> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Password'.

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -Username mydbuser -ServerInstance 192.168.3.42\DB -Database MyDatabase -Query "SELECT * FROM Schools" -Password `@pswrd
```

Results in data returned from the call.

I'm still not sure how to translate that to the DevOps Release Task.

Comment: What task are you using to execute sql scripts?

Comment: Task         : SQL Server database deploy
Description  : Deploy a SQL Server database using DACPAC or SQL scripts
Version      : 0.3.23
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group

Comment: You'll likely have to change your password to exclude a few special characters.

>If used in an OLE DB or ODBC connection string, a login or password must not contain the following characters: [] () , ; ? * ! @ =. These characters are used to either initialize a connection or separate connection values.

from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/strong-passwords?view=sql-server-ver15


I don't know if the task uses ODBC to connect, or just has a bug when it comes to escaping passwords. You may also want to log a bug against the task in github.